# separating spans to two lines in panel heading when on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel with a panel heading like this below and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to split into two lines when on mobile < 480px and one line when greater then 480px

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey;">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em; color: #777;"> 
<span>panel heading text</span><span> more text</span>
   </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [mediaqueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries),

> Media queries are useful when you want to modify your site or app depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen) or specific characteristics and parameters (such as screen resolution or browser viewport width).

basic code could be :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

demo:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 1px solid lightgrey;">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em; color: #777;">
    <span>panel heading text</span><span> more text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```